# Error title not showing in text field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title", class: "form-control",pattern: "[a-zA-Z\s]{1,}", title: "Enter only alphabets",:required=>true %>
 </div>
```

It only highlight border but not showing error

[image]

Comment: Is this after you submit the form, or before?

Comment: after.......before submit nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Don't use placeholders as a replacement for labels.

> Provide labels to identify all form controls, including text fields,
>   checkboxes, radio buttons, and drop-down menus. In most cases this is
>   done by using the  element.
>   https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels

The major drawback of using placeholders in this way is that once the user starts filling out the form there is not longer any visual clues at all for the user as to which field is which. This especially applies if the user posts the form with empty fields and it is re-rendered. Its also a huge accessibility fail for people who depend on assistive technologies.

Instead you want to use CSS to inset label tge in the input. [There are quite a few ways to do this.](https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/). The simplest being something like this:

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}
.row > label {
  position: absolute;
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <label for="foo">Foo</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo">
</div>
```